kubuntu 22.04 won't run PHP cronjobs normally anymore (logs stay empty, script is never ran)
i have a PHP script that has ran correctly up to about 3 or 4 days ago, also from crontab.
it fetches RSS news items and puts them into a db.
the problem i have at the moment is that this script will no longer run from crontab.
it will still function when ran from a sudo environment in konsole.
root@parakeet:/var/www/nicer.app/NicerAppWebOS/apps/NicerAppWebOS/applications/2D/news# source "/var/www/nicer.app/NicerAppWebOS/scripts.install/install.cron.d/nicerapp__init_globals.sh" && php "/var/www/nicer.app/NicerAppWebOS/apps/NicerAppWebOS/applications/2D/news/crontabEntry_manageDatabase.php" >> "$NA_LOGS_PATH/$dateMinutesSeconds-news_crontabEntry_manageDatabase.txt" 2>&1


oh, the cronjob needs to specify where this script is ran from, because it relies on $_SERVER variables being "correct"..
root@parakeet:#crontab -e
*/5 * * * * cd "/var/www/nicer.app/NicerAppWebOS/scripts.install" && source "/var/www/nicer.app/NicerAppWebOS/scripts.install/install.cron.d/nicerapp__init_globals.sh" && php "/var/www/nicer.app/NicerAppWebOS/apps/NicerAppWebOS/applications/2D/news/crontabEntry_manageDatabase.php" >> "$NA_LOGS_PATH/$dateMinutesSeconds-news_crontabEntry_manageDatabase.txt" 2>&1
this works as intended for me.
URL = https://nicer.app/world-news
